# AngularJS Form Post After Model Updates

Tags: angularjs

This seems to be stupid but basically what I'm trying to achieve is very simple. I have a Controller function that updates my model and after that I must do a submit.

The problem: The submit occurs before the DOM elements receive the value accordingly to the model and the POST data goes empty.

Follows my fiddle problem: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriobarreto/ctguarms/)

AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]).run(function($rootScope){
      $rootScope.Query = { Name: null, Age: null };

      $rootScope.Submit = function(){
           $rootScope.Query.Name = 'Roger';
           $rootScope.Query.Age = '34';

           document.getElementById('frmApp').submit();
      }
})
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <form id="frmApp" target="ifrmTarget" action="anywhere">
          <input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="Query.Name" />
          <input type="text" name="Age" ng-model="Query.Age" />
          <a ng-click="Submit()">Some Title</a>
    </form>
    <iframe name="ifrmTarget"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: try $apply or $digest... but, what's the point to allow the user to input something if you are changing it?

Comment: In real application those are hidden fields, I tryed the $apply, but angular says its alrady in an $apply

Comment: Actually I can acchieve a solution using a $timeout service, but I feel sick with that anti-pattern sollution. AngularTeam should give us an "Angular DOM Ready Wrapper" for this cases, or I am missing something...

Comment: It never happened to me to be in need of such kind of solution, also because of the iframe that in this case is a black-box, but I think that this can be a javascript issue, not an angular specific. But I can be wrong. I will spend some time tonight if I can looking for a solution. Did you find anything in the official documentation?

Comment: Im not using iframe in application, the iframe was only to not submit out of jsfiddle and keep watching the network tab of browser developer view. And as u can see, the values are not passed in querystring data

Comment: Then, just use a function on click And use the Query object.... am I understanding it wrong?